# Double join query returning multiple identical records instead of unique ones

Tags: linq-to-sql

I am trying to get the teams a person belongs to using this query. The problem is that it returns the teams of all the departments of the team the person is in (I get multiple identical records back). I guess I have to replace the .contains but I can't figure out with what as I'm a complete newb and I can't find any helpful examples with double joins. What do I have to change to make it work as intended? Thanks in advance.

```
public IQueryable<Team> GetTeamsByPersonID(int id)
    {
        return from t in entities.Teams
               join d in entities.Departments
                on t.TeamID equals d.TeamID
               where (from p in entities.Person_Departments
                      join dep in entities.Departments
                      on p.DepartmentID equals dep.DepartmentID
                      where p.PersonID == id
                      select dep.TeamID).Contains(d.TeamID)
               select t;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
return (
from t in entities.Teams
from d in entities.Departments
from p in entities.Person_Departments
where t.TeamID == d.TeamID && p.DepartmentID == d.DepartmentID && p.PersonID == id
select t
).Distinct();
```